# Web fonts appear jagged after using other browsers

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, font-face

I know there are a lot of other questions regarding the "jagged" or "pixelated" fonts problem, but here's the weird thing, for me at least..

After building a site locally and testing in Firefox, the font loaded from Google Webfonts looked great. Almost Photoshop quality. It was only after I had tested the site in some other browsers, such as IE, Opera, Chrome and Safari, that when I returned to Firefox the font started to appear jagged.

I'm wondering if when I loaded up the other browser, it changed a setting somewhere on my PC. I have a AMD Advent Monza S150 with Windows 7.

I've also messed around with the ClearType option but still no luck. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

More of a shot in the dark, than the real answer, but... one reason that could be that the font you are using on your website is installed on your PC. Google webfonts, and webfonts in general usually have the downside of looking good only with certain font sizes.